# Java - JTextArea into JList does not show the wanted text

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea, jlist

Ok guys here is the deal, I am trying to populate a JList's rows using a JtextArea that contains a string value, but when I run my program all that is shown in the JList's rows are the JTextArea's properties(?) instead of the string I am passing. So, can you please take a look at my code and point out what i am missing?

Here is the Code:

```
public void DoConnect() {
    try{
             String host="jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/Project";
             String username="Adminn";
             String pass="password";
             Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection( host, username, pass );
             System.out.println("connected");

             Statement stmt = con.createStatement( );
             String SQL = "SELECT * FROM TEAMS";
             ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery(SQL);

             while(rs.next()){

             String s = rs.getString("NAME");

             JTextArea ta = new JTextArea();
             ta.setText(s);
             listModel.addElement(ta);
             }
             jList1.setModel(listModel);
             jButton1.addActionListener ((ActionEvent e) -> {
                listModel.removeAllElements();
                DoConnect();
             });

        }
        catch ( SQLException err ){
             System.out.println( err.getMessage( ) );
        }
}
```

And here is the output I am getting:

[image]

Comment: `then the JtextArea to the JList to be displayed` why do you care about the JTextArea? The String data is what is important.

Comment: Because the string I am trying to display has multiple lines. So I figured that in order to be displayed correctly I have to use a JTextArea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default renderer of a JList simply displays the `toString()` implementation of the object that you add to the model.

Don't add a JTextArea to the ListModel. Add the `String` to the `ListModel`

Also, why are you using "select * from Teams" when you only want a single column of data. Be more explicit with your SQL and make the query more efficient.

Edit:

> Because the string I am trying to display has multiple lines.

Then you need to create a custom renderer and use the JTextArea as the renderer. In any case you would only ever add the String text to the ListModel. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Writing a Custom Renderer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html#renderer).

Or a second option is to display the text as HTML. A JLabel will render the HTML in multiple line:

```
listModel.addElement("<html>1<br>2<br>3<br></html>");
```

Comment: Try the suggestion. It is only line of code. Then tell us why you don't like the solution that we have given you. The default renderer for a JList is a JLabel and you simply add a String to the label. You can't just display a JTextArea unless you create a custom renderer and you haven't given us any reason why you might want to go to all this trouble to do this.

Comment: As I said above to camickr, the string I am passing has multiple lines so wouldn't it be better if i used a JTextArea?

Comment: Also I have tried your suggestion and the string is displayed in a single row.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need JTable and not JTextArea for that purpose, correct me if i'm wrong.
For example, [check this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JX9xm.png)

If you want to go with the JTable solution, there is a library called `rs2xml.jar` which makes your life easier to populate JTable with the data you wanted.

Usage:

```
Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
String SQL = "SELECT * FROM TEAMS";
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(SQL);
table.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs)); //this line requires the rs2xml.jar
```

Credits to: http://learnerarena.com for the picture.
Sorry, i could not comment due to low reputation.

Comment: @SoCo Updated my answer a bit to help you out some more.